# Problem starting jupyter lab from anaconda

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-lab

i got this message starting jupyter-lab from anaconda:

```
[I 19:17:39.382 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\difer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 19:17:39.382 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\difer\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 19:17:39.611 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\difer
[I 19:17:39.611 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 19:17:39.611 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=987cd58e531edc3bff0dertb28b2fd17rrr6b4b87898e08f89ed56
[I 19:17:39.611 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=987cd58e531ederc3bff0db2ert8b2fd176b4b8ert7898e08f89ed56
[I 19:17:39.611 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 19:17:39.658 LabApp]
```

I tried double Ctrl-C and nothing. Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it started just fine. Ctrl-c stops the server. Can you share want command you used to start it?

Comment: I tried to open from anaconda and anaconda prompt (using 'jupyter-lab') and in both cases opens an empty browser page.

Comment: I got this: [I 20:05:57.161 LabApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 20:05:57.161 LabApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 20:05:57.161 LabApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.

Comment: That probably means you are already running a jupyter session. Make sure to stop all the previously running instances of Jupyter. ```CTRL + C``` and then it prompts you to confirm with ```Y```. Then restart your jupyter with ```jupyter-lab``` and go to [http://localhost:8888/lab](http://localhost:8888/lab)

Comment: I agree the CWB's comment that you are already running an instance of Jupyter. But I would suggest going a step or two further.  Open the Windows Task Manager, click on Details,  Sort by the Name, then scroll down to see how many instances of Jupyter are Running.  I use Bash to start Jupyter which can cause many running instances of Jupyter.  At the moment my computer shows 6 running instances.  When these running instances get too large, I reboot the computer.   And FYI, by using Anaconda, you are putting an unknown element between you and your software.

Comment: It could be something with anaconda. I opened jupyterlab from windows command prompt and I had no problem, I changed environment in anaconda, no problem. It was a problem of the environment I was working. I closed all the jupyter instance in the task manager but that didn´t solve my problem.